# Selecting the first value from the given column (without using pandas)

Tags: python, dataset

I have a column which is shown below:

```
370
370
370
371
371
371
371
371
371
371
371
371
371
372
372
372
```

I want to select only the first value for the beginning of the number. 
Here is the code I've used. (Not using pandas).

```
import os
with open ("file") as data:
    p= list(data)
o=[]
for t in p: 
    k= t.split()
    if k[0] == 'some value':
        if k[4] == 'A':
            o= k[5]
```

The output should be something like:

```
370
371
372
```

Comment: Do you want to identify all of the unique values?  If so, you can use `set(p)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried using it, but the output is not what I want. I've mentioned the desired output, but set(p) is giving me something like this: {'3', '7', '1'}
{'2', '3', '7'} {'2', '3', '7'}
{'2', '3', '7'}

Comment: When you import your file, use `p = data.readlines()` to get a list with each line as a new element.

Comment: there is something missing here.  @ChrisMueller 's answer is correct. according to your data, `p` should be `['370\n', '370\n' ... ]`. `set(p)` should give the desired result.  try printing out `p` and see if it's correct

Comment: I tried using the readlines method, but it still gives me the same output {'1', '3', '7'}
{'1', '3', '7'}
{'2', '3', '7'}
{'2', '3', '7'}. I think the problem is occuring since I'm selecting only one column from the data and hence, when i try set(p), i get the whole data separated by '\n', but I wanted only the 5th column.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
with open('tmp.txt') as fp:
    # turn it into a set of lines - duplicates are ignored
    nums = set(fp.readlines())
    # remove whitespace around those lines and turn them to integers
    nums = {int(num.strip()) for num in nums}

print(nums)
```

And read up on how to use [sets](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset). They're super useful!

Comment: I'm getting this output: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x000001DF09A494F8>

Comment: @Dustrokes are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: I use python 3 only

Comment: I ran that code and it worked for me. I'm not sure what's wrong with yours.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using:

```
import os
with open("file") as data:
   p = data.read().splitlines()
set(p)
```

which returns just the unique values:

```
{'370', '371', '372'}
```

The issue you're presently having is you're not just getting data:

```
import os
with open ("file") as data:
    p= list(data)
p
```

returns data with newline characters:

```
['370\n',
 '370\n',
 '370\n',
 '371\n',
 '371\n',
 '371\n',
 '371\n',
 '371\n',
 '371\n',
 '371\n',
 '371\n',
 '371\n',
 '371\n',
 '372\n',
 '372\n',
 '372\n']
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried this method, but the result I'm getting is something like this: Any idea why the curly brackets are present here. {'3', '5'}
{'6', '3', '5'}
{'6', '3', '5'}

Comment: Maybe a communication barrier-- the key to doing this is using the "p = data.read().splitlines()" part _before_ trying to do the rest. That solves it. It works, I tried it on my own system.

Comment: until recently I was able to replicate the error you saw.  As of now I'm not getting that error. The only thing that I changed was updating my system.  Now I get the expected `{'370\n', '371\n', '372\n'}` or `{'370', '371', '372'}` when using the `set` method depending on how I obtain the data from file.

Have you attempted updating your python?

Comment: I haven't updated python yet, I'll check for the updates and will get back to you. Thanks for the information!!

Comment: I haven't updated python yet, I'll check for the updates and will get back to you. Thanks for the information!!